# Como puedo personalizar el queryset de la vista genérica ListView en Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, django-views

Básicamente me gustaría aplicarles unos filtros, no quiero que muestre todos los elementos.

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega lo que llevas y los errores obtenidos al momento

Answer (score 3):

Para eso tendrás que sobrescribir el método `get_queryset` y retornar el `QuerySet` con los filtros que quieras, etc.

> **¿Qué hace el método `get_queryset`?**
>
> Devuelve la lista de elementos para esta vista.
>
> El valor de retorno debe ser un iterable y puede ser una instancia de
>   `QuerySet` en cuyo caso se habilitará el comportamiento específico de`QuerySet`.

Un ejemplo de su uso:

```
class MyModelListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "template.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyMode.objects.exclude(quantity = 0)
```

En este caso estamos retornando un `QuerySet` en el cual excluimos los objetos que tengan como valor 0 en el campo `quantity`.

Para mas información te sugiero revisar esto:
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_queryset